# The size of a class within a class

Tags: c++

Why is the of the object of class A - 4 bytes(its not considering classes B and C).

And how do i create object A such that B and C are also created?

Would then the size of object change? If no then are objects B and C still considered to be a *part of* object A itself?

```
class A
{
public:
        A()
        {
                a=9;
                //B objB; //you wont be able to call since A::B::B() is private
                //C objC; //same as above
        }
        int a;
        class B
        {
                B()
                {
                        b=10;
                }
                int b;
        };

        class C
        {
        public:
                int c,d,e,f,g;
        };
};
```

Comment: Why would A instances be larger than 4 bytes ? Neither `objB` nor `objC` are *members* of `A`. They're automatic variables.

Comment: @WhozCraig : I'm not sure i understood you. These are not auto variables. I didn't understand why shouldn't the sizeof B and C be a part of A?

Comment: *"These are not auto variables"* - **yes they are**.I Ahmed's answer spells it out *exactly*. If you think `objB` or `objC` contribute you the logical or physical representation of an instance of `A`, you're understanding is not correct. That's how the language works. Move them out of the constructor and make them members of `A` just like `a` is, and they will join the folly. If you added a 4KB variable to `A::A()` that does nothing to the instance size of an `A`. Move it to be a member and it is now part of (and therefore contributes to the size of) an `A`.

Answer (score 2):

Because, in the class A only `int a;` is member variable in the class scope which is counted as size of the class.

The class itself don't take any space, until the object is created. You have created object using the following code, but the code will not be executed as constructor for B is private, if you make it public constructor for class B and C and add it as follows in constructor of A:

```
B objB; 
C objC;
```

Which is local in the constructor and deallocated after constructor finished executing.

Comment: B objB is not correct. The code wont compile. Because of the reason mentioned in the comment.

Comment: I have commented those two lines to make my question more clear.

Comment: The question is really not about B being private or not. The question is more about B's existence inside A. Precisely there are three questions written in my main question

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to understand is that class declaration is like a blueprint and does not occupy any data memory. So classes B and C are present but dont occupy any memory as object is not instantiated.

You are creating local variables of it in the constructor of A.

```
class A
{
    public:
    int a;
    int x; //added an additional variable (this should increase the size of object to 8)
    A()
    {
        a=9;           
        //Below 2 objects are allocated on stack not object memory     
        B objB; 
        C objC; 
        //Memory for objects objB and objC are released after exit from constructor
    }

    //class B and C are accessible only within class A
    class B
    {
        public: //made public so object can be instantiated.
            int b;
            B()
            {
                b=10;
            }

    };

    class C
    {
        public:
            int c,d,e,f,g;
    };        
};
```

Adding integer x within class A will increase the size by another 4 bytes.
The total size for the above class is now 8 bytes.
Any number of local variables declared within constructor will not increase the size of the class.

Comment: Please note the code won't even compile because of the reason mentioned in the comment. so there is no question of it getting created. The question is more towards why the object A doesnt have object B and C inside it. Why does the size remain the same?

Comment: I have commented those two lines to make my question more clear.

Comment: By declaring Class B and C within class A you are saying that these classes are visible only within A. The object you have declared in the constructor is a local variable and the memory is allocated on stack, not part of the object memory.

Comment: I believe you have not noticed the change that the A's constructor doesnt create object B and C :)

Comment: About your question in the comments, by declaring class B and C you are not saying a obj of class B and C are created when obj of A is created. You are mentioning that obj of class B and C can be created only by functions with class A. Unless you have objB = new B() or B objB statement an object is not created. By including class B and C within A you will increase code memory size and not object memory size. Hope this helps. https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/size_of_class_object.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between a definition and its instances. When you do a sizeof of an object, you calculate the size of the instance, not of the class. Since the only information specific to an instance of A is the integer a, the instance is only of the size of an integer.

B and C are not part of the definition of A. You may have declared classes B and C in the scope of A, but since you don't declare any B or C member within A, well, there is no instance of B nor C in the memory of A.

The classes B and C are indeed created, but can only be used in the context of A (it's the point of declaring them within A).